# Give a trace for LSD string sort (sometimes called LSD radix sort) of 23 49 33 48 42

Tags: sorting, radix

I am preparing myself for the algorithm exam, and I am unsure if I did this question right.

[Image - question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sopvg.png)

I came up to, by using the LSD algorithm that the following trace occur during the algorithm:

Trace:

- 23, 49, 33, 48, 42
- 42, 23, 33, 48, 49
- 23, 33, 42, 48, 49

Which means, the answer for this question must be A as my result matches to answer A. Could some one tell me if i did this right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's correct.  You used LSD properly.